# java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation for javax.xml.xpath.XPath.setNamespaceContext

Tags: java, xml, xpath, jboss

```
import javax.xml.namespace.NamespaceContext;
XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
xpath.setNamespaceContext(some code goes here)
```

I use `javax.xml.namespace.NamespaceContext` in my web app and when deployed on jboss server, it gives out following error:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: when resolving interface method "javax.xml.xpath.XPath.setNamespaceContext(Ljavax/xml/namespace/NamespaceContext;)V" the class loader (instance of org/jboss/classloader/spi/base/BaseClassLoader) of the current class, com/accenture/mdh/sso/util/Util, and the class loader (instance of <bootloader>) for resolved class, javax/xml/xpath/XPath, have different Class objects for the type )V used in the signature
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doHandlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:852)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.handlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:781)
    org.apache.jsp.jsp.LoginConsumer_jsp._jspService(LoginConsumer_jsp.java:187)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:369)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:322)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:249)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
```

I searched through the internet and it seems like there is conflicting jars with `javax.xml.namespace.NamespaceContext` in WEB-INF/lib. However, I am still unable to find the cause. Really appreciate your thoughts.

Comment: do you have one or two of those jars?

Comment: Had an unused jar "javax.xml.stream_1.0.1.v201004272200.jar" which has the same namespace. Even after removing it, still I get the same error

Answer (score 0):

Excluding below libraries which had the same package name of `javax.xml.namespace.NamespaceContext` resolved the issue.

- stax-api.jar
- javax.xml.stream_1.0.1.v201004272200.jar